# Proper way to call boost io_service.post

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio, stdstring

I have the following functions:

```
void MyLib::sendMessage(const std::string& message) {
  m_xIOService.post( boost::bind(&VoIPPhone::onSendMessage, this, message) );
}

void MyLib::onSendMessage(const std::string& message) {
  m_xVoIPClient.sendMessage(message);
}
```

So I call sendMessagein one thread and onSendMessage will be invoked in main thread.

The question is will be message string copied by boost in this case or not. If no - how can I pass string into onSendMessage function and be sure that there will no memory leak and message string is valid, not deleted object?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`onSendMessage` will be invoked in one of the threads that execute `m_xIOService::run` - not in the main thread.

All `bind` arguments are copied, so `message` will be copied as well. Whenever you want to pass `bind` parameters by reference, use `boost::ref` wrapper.